# Clearing an ActionItem in refresh code

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to clear an ActionItem in refresh code. I am using the ActiomBarSherlock component and I have my action item filtering but want to clear it when not in a menu driven event.

Can someone help me with the proper way to access it without holding onto my menu in a global variable? I tried to just reference the TextView directly but it is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with keeping a reference to a MenuItem to interact with it at a later time. You can also call invalidateOptionsMenu so that onCreateOptionsMenu will be called again and you can update the menu state.

Comment: Thanks ended up keeping a reference to the menu.